# How to shift the tick labels between two ticks python plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I have created a plot bar using `plotly`. An `xticklabel` is under each bar. Is it possible to shift the `xticklabels` a bit to the right or the left or even in the middle between two ticks?

```
import plotly

import pandas as pd
from plotly.graph_objs import * 


json_file = {'y': [0, 1, 2, 3, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(json_file, index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])

trace1 = Bar(
    x=df.index,
    y=df['y'])

layout = Layout(
        xaxis=XAxis(
            ticks=df.index,
            tickvals=df.index))

data = Data([trace1])

fig = Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
plotly.offline.plot(fig)
```

A part of the result is the following:
[image]

Is there a way to place `b` between the two bars?

Comment: You did ask this same question two hours ago (which you just deleted).

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel it was suggested to be deleted as it lacked information for people to help

Comment: A comparison between both questions was the same text with a slightly different title (one word).